# Font loading with next.js and style jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I recently began converting my create react app application to next.js. I'm using vercel's open source next.js website as a guide to structuring mine. I declared a font.ts and used style jsx file and imported it into the _app.js but when i use the font I get a 404 from the server.

This is the font.ts file:

```
import css from 'styled-jsx/css'

export default css.global`
    /* latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: bon;
        font-display: auto;
        src: url('../public/static/fonts/Bon.woff2') format('woff2');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: bonitalic;
        font-display: auto;
        src: url('../public/static/fonts/Bonitalic.woff2') format('woff2');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: maison;
        font-display: auto;
        src: url('../public/static/fonts/MaisonNeue-Book.woff2') format('woff2');
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the font files that you need to use here is their public URL, not their filesystem location. So instead of `url('../public/static/fonts/...')` just use `url('/static/fonts/...')`.